# Property into AppComponent returns empty value Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying the heros tutorial from the angular 2 official site:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

But I can't retrieve the values for AppComponent, it always returns an empty value.

Here the code of app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Titulo: {{titulo}}</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    titulo: 'Tour de heroes';
}
```

When I save the changes and refresh the page I only get: Titulo:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `titulo = 'Tour de heroes'`, not `titulo: 'Tour de heroes'`.

`:` is used to assign type to variable, `=` is used to assign value to variable. Example:

```
titulo: string = 'Tour de heroes'
```

The code above declares variable `titulo` of type `string` and assigns value `Tour de heroes` to it.